# I am calling a jquery function from html select and accessing some object in jquery function. but is comes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#branddrop').change(function getModels(){
        console.log('entered')
        brand = $(this).val();
        console.log(brand);
        console.log("http://localhost:8006/api/models/" + String(brand['name']));
        $.get("http://localhost:8006/api/models/", 
        function(data) {
            var models = $('#model');

            models.empty();

            $.each(data, function(i, value) {       
                models
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",value.name)
                    .text(value.name)); 
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

I am able to console the `brand` as

```
{"id":5,"name":"LeEco","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

but when console the `brand['name']` i get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the brand variable holds the string value `'{"id":5,"name":"LeEco","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}'`

You might have to parse the string into an object as follows:

```
var brandObj = JSON.parse(brand);
brandObj['name'] // should work
```